# Load Codeigniter into Eclipse to work on more projects similar to CodeIgniter Video tutorials

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I use codeigniter along with XAMPP (all in one :-D, very nice!) for php coding and I too fall for these two basic tutorials http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/. I think about Eclipse as a similar editor, similar to the one the tutor is using in the videos. **But I am unable to figure out how to load all files/folders into the eclipse, the same done by the editor in the videos.**
I am totally new to apache settings; I change the port number, and set the webserver to start running at codeigniter's unzipped directory (C:\CodeIgniter\). It works, but in Eclipse, everytime I create a new project, it asks me to fill in the project name (set in the workspace C:\EclipseWorkspace\) then if I want to add a new file, I have to choose the container name (the project name). **I don't know how this is reset to match the webserver document root to make it work in the browser.** Thank you for any instructions.

Comment: so you are wanting your eclipse to be setup in your XAMPP web directory?

Answer (score 1):

When Eclipse loads, make your workspace the same as your htroot (I think that is what it is called in XAMPP??) directory...  This way when you make a new file or directory or update a file, all you have to do is click "save" in eclipse, and the file will be saved to your web root directory, and you should be able to see your changes by refreshing your browser.

I used XAMPP too when I was first learning PHP, but after I discovered how to make a full lamp stack in Linux I abandoned XAMPP in favor of an environment that would more closely match a production environment.  XAMPP is suitable only for development, even the project itself states that XAMPP should not be used for a production environment, plus I had issues with XAMPP not being able to start the Apache web service -- Steam Games would interfere with the XAMPP apache app.